# select Data between start year and start month to end year and end month?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to select the rows for given range of year and month. `(i.e.: from <start year>+<start month> to <end year>+<end month>).`

I have Used Following Table.

```
Id  Page_id Url Score   Month   Year
1   1      Link  192     4      2015
2   1      Link  247     5      2015
3   1      Link  304     6      2015
4   1      Link  283     7      2015
.                   
.                   
10  1      Link  288     1      2016
11  1      Link  295     2      2016
12  1      Link  393     3      2016
```

I am Fetched Data From `( <5+2015> to <2+2016> )`.
I tried the below query but I am getting unexpected rows. Am I missing something?

```
SELECT * FROM `readability` AS t WHERE  t.url
       BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('5', '2015'), '%Y%m') AND 
               LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2', '2016'), '%Y%m'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Ye,s you seem to be missing a lot.  What does the `url` have to do with the condition you want.

Presumably, you want:

```
where year * 100 + month between 201505 and 201602
```

Your data has no date columns.  You *could* convert everything to dates, but integer (or string) comparisons are sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your data about dates to dates mysql data type.

Then just make a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `readability` WHERE  (date_field BETWEEN '2015-01-05' AND '2016-01-02');
```